# Building Firefox os for Nexus 7 ( grouper ) gets error messages by using Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: android, c++, ubuntu, firefox-os

I'm still building Firefox OS for Nexus 7 ( grouper ) by using Ubuntu 13.10.
( Follow the instruction from : https://wiki.mozilla.org/B2G/Nexus7 )
After had been fixing lots of problems, I encountered a issue.

Error messages showed :

```
...
../../dist/include/mozilla/BloomFilter.h: In static member function 'static bool mozilla::BloomFilter<KeySize, T>::full(const uint8_t&)':
../../dist/include/mozilla/BloomFilter.h:160:60: error: 'UINT8_MAX' was not declared in this scope
...
make[7]: *** [TestBloomFilter.o] Error 1
make[7]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
...
make[6]: *** [libs] Error 2
```

And I checked the ../mbft/BloomFilter.h code.
I think UINT8_MAX can be defined by including a file which is mozilla/StandardInteger.h

(1). BloomFilter.h part of content :

```
#ifndef mozilla_BloomFilter_h_
#define mozilla_BloomFilter_h_

#include "mozilla/Assertions.h"
#include "mozilla/Likely.h"
#include "mozilla/StandardInteger.h"
#include "mozilla/Util.h"

#include <string.h>
...
```

(2). StandardInteger.h content :

```
#ifndef mozilla_StandardInteger_h_
#define mozilla_StandardInteger_h_

#if defined(MOZ_CUSTOM_STDINT_H)
#  include MOZ_CUSTOM_STDINT_H
#elif defined(_MSC_VER) && _MSC_VER < 1600
#  include "mozilla/MSStdInt.h"
#else
#  include <stdint.h>
#endif

#endif  /* mozilla_StandardInteger_h_ */
```

I added var UINT8_MAX in BloomFilter.h, but there were more similar error occurred such as " UINT32_MAX was not declared ...".
How can I correctly include the right variables ?

Thanks !